# check for array1's values in array2

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Having the following two different arrays in php:

```
Array1
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => William
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Bob
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Michael
        )

)
Array2
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11128
            [name] => John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11127
            [name] => Adam
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11126
            [name] => Andrew
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11125
            [name] => William
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11124
            [name] => Bob
        )

)
```

Can I somehow find matching `name`s so the output will be like:

```
Array1 (1, id:2) matches Array2 (4, id:11124) with name: Bob
Array1 (0, id:1) matches Array2 (3, id:11125) with name: William
```

*sorry if it's unclear*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always try a simple foreach loop:

```
<?php
foreach($array1 as $key1=>$value1) {
    foreach($array2 as $key2=>$value2) {
        if($value1['name'] === $value2['name']) {
            sprintf('Array1 (%d, id:%d) matches Array2 (%d, id:%d) with name: %s', $key1, $value1['id'], $key2, $value2['id'], $value1['name']);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array1 as $i=>$x){
  foreach($array2 as $k=>$y){
    if($x['name'] == $y['name']){
      echo "Array1 ($i, id:{$x['id']}) matches Array2 ($k, id:{$y['id']}) with name: {$x['name']}\n";
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for us having identical code except for the sprintf vs echo!

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: And I have a `break` after the echo :-P

Comment: well true, and an empty result array. I think you could have outdone me if you stored the matches in it and then mapped them to `vsprintf`.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: Oops.  I was gonna use the `$result` array, but then I didn't.